# Is SD card working on another Raspberry PI?

Tags: sd-card

I did a lot of works on my old PI, which was bought by Uni. I returned it except the SD card (which I bought) last week and then found out some of results hadn't been recorded. So I bought a new PI on my own.

Quick question: Will SD card work on a new PI smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether the hardware of the two Pis were similar revisions.  I believe at some stage the hardware changed and new firmware was required to boot properly.

If your SD card has the old firmware it may fail to boot the "newer" Pi.

If it doesn't you'll need to upgrade the firmware on the SD card or extract any needed files and then re-image the SD card.  To do either of those you'll need to find a Linux machine with an SD card reader.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I got your point, so is there any method that I can get the file from SD card directly? I am using Mac OSX.

Comment: All your files will be in the ext4 partition of the SD card.  I'm not familiar with Mac OSX.  On A Windows PC you could boot up a Linux Live CD (no need to install) and use that to extract the files.

Comment: Sounds like a useful method, I'll try to figure it out. Thank you so much.

Comment: I copied my files on Ubuntu. And used SD card on new PI, it functioned directly.